# GCC <includes> multiple sub folders

Tags: c

I want to compile some C code with GCC but having problems with linking the necessary files.

I have a simple .c file that includes 3 header files from other repo projects that I have downloaded and put in my working folder. The `-I` command lets me add folders to the compilation but it fails on one of the repos because it seems like the command is not recursively looking through subfolders.

How do I tell the compiler that he has to look for includes in all subfolders of my current working directory ?

Comment: You have to specify each folder on your own. Normally if a project provides nested include folders, you are supposed to use the path, e.g. `#include "gtk/gtk.h"` Why would you want to have the compiler search in other folders? If you just don't want to type the extra path in the include directive, you might have some hard timewith programming...

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Comment: This would normally be the responsibility of a build configuration tool like CMake.